# Handling of DbSet by raw sql queries

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I would like to know how to handle SQL query right in EF6. I had the normal

```
DbSet<NameOfTableinDB> TableName {get; set; }
```

Because I don't know how much columns and which datatypes are return by the query.

For example I can return 2 columns with type of string return. With a join statement I can return easily 6 columns with 3 different types (int, string, datetime).

Do I have to create a new

```
public class SomeName {
  public string someValue {get; set;}
  ....
}
```

for each SQL statement?

Comment: All your queries are using the same table `TableName`?

Comment: No, there not using the same table. 
Here is the statement: 

     SELECT g.groupID, g.groupName, (SELECT count(groupID) FROM crayfire_address WHERE groupID = g.groupID) as addressCount FROM crayfire_address_group AS g

Comment: So if they don't use the same table and can query multiple table at once you  should create custom classes DTO to map to the result.

Comment: I think OP simply missed `select new { ...  }`.